Is this a wordplay?
I came across this sentence while playing the game UFO: A Day In The Life.

おいチ
わかいチ
とってもおいチ！

The context is the following: You caught a flea that was stinging a girl, and after you do so it says the aforementioned quote. My guess is that it was a wordplay with 血 and 美味しい. This would be my translation:

Old (person's) blood
Young (Person's) blood
(It doesn't matter who it belongs to) it's very tasty!

I don't know how to translate the pun to english, but I want to make sure if it's posible that it is a pun or maybe there is another interpretation I didn't think of.

Mispronouncing し as ち is common among small Japanese children. It's similar to how English-speaking children pronounce "rabbit" as "wabbit". So if we consider し and ち the same, these three phrases rhyme perfectly and can be seen as a form of wordplay, though not a pun in the strict sense.
Note that おい is probably just a part of おいしい, not 老い. 老い is a noun meaning "aging" or "senescence", and 老い血 is ungrammatical. This line seems to be just "おいしい、若い血、とってもおいしい (Yummy, young blood, very yummy!)" to me.

Indeed. If it were intended to refer to both old and young people's blood, I would expect a どっチも to get thrown in there somewhere too.
